# Cannot register bean definition for bean that is already defined in TestConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, testcontainers, spring-boot-configuration

I have a DataJpaTest with testcontainers for testing my database repositories, such as

```
@DataJpaTest  
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)  
@Testcontainers 
@ActiveProfiles("test")  
class OrderRepositoryTest
```

I'm using @ActiveProfiles("test") to be able to config my test application via application-test.yml

Also I have a test configuration class for entities and repositories

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.sample.logistics"
})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
        "com.sample.logistics"
})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.schema}")
    private String schema;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getTestDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSourceBuilder = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSourceBuilder.setUrl(url);
        dataSourceBuilder.setSchema(schema);
        dataSourceBuilder.setUsername(userName);
        dataSourceBuilder.setPassword(password);
        return dataSourceBuilder;
    }

}
```

Tests are working well, but I have a problem with launching my main Spring Boot Application, it falls with the following problem.

`Cannot register bean definition for bean 'orderRequestTemplateRepository' since there is already [Root bean: class ; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null; defined in com.sample.logistics.order_requests.dao.repository.OrderRequestTemplateRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TestConfig] bound.`

Seems like some beans were registered by my TestConfig class, but I have no idea, why did TestConfig actually work here. I was expecting that it will be ignored because it's located in src.test.java package.

How can I ignore TestConfig in my main application?

I tried to set parameter spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true, but it didn't work.

With this parameter I had the following problem:
`
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.sample.logistics.order_requests.service.OrderRequestServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.`

Comment: Why do you have the configuration in the first place? That shouldn't be needed, Spring Boot will detect the main class and scan and register beans from there. The `@DataJpaTest` will only register repositories and other JPA related things. So the config shouldn't be necessary, if you did it to solve an issue you probably found the wrong solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum I had several reasons for this. First, I'm working on a big project, which consists of several modules, and the main class located in another module, which is not a parent of the module where the test is running. Second, I wanted to override some beans of main application, such as DataSource.

Comment: Overriding the datasource is easier with a specific properties file for testing, but alas. The class should also not be annotated with `@SpringBootConfiguration` as there should only be one (which is the actual application). There is a special `@TestConfiguration` for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum `@TestConfiguration` doesn't work. Moreover, with @TestConfiguration I have tests failing with error `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`. That's why I'm using `@SpringBootConfiguration`

Comment: That error is due to using Spring Boot test support in a non spring boot project. With non-spring boot I mean here a project that doesn't include the `@SpringBootApplication` class. Which basically makes it a regular Spring application.

Comment: But my App is Spring Boot. So what should I do with my application and tests?

Comment: Your final application is your module isn't, hence the workarounds you need to apply to get something working. Add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to your `@SpringBootConfiguration` class to have auto-config re-enabled (normally this is through `@SpringBootApplication`. I also wonder is this really a separate module (maven/gradle project) or part of a larger mono repo for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Check your spring application's main class to see if the @ComponentScan includes the path of the test package as well.
Such as:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sf.slg.*"})
```

and your test path just happens to be com.sf.slg.test.xxx